# Sort Visual Studio 2017 compiler warnings by date modified (SVN)

Tags: visual-studio, svn, warnings, compiler-warnings

In my project I have a lot of warnings (500+), and I want to let the developers in my team know that their newly written code has warnings.

Is there anyway to sort all of these warnings by date modified? Perhaps some SVN command?

Comment: How do these warnings relate to SVN and how do you integrate SVN with Visual Studio?

Comment: The date of which thing being modified? Source file? Line of code? You might be able to check out previous revisions, do a build, save the compiler warnings that came out, and diff them against newer revisions. Then you can say "revision xyz introduced these compiler warnings".

Comment: @bahrep I am using VisualSVN for Visual Studio integration  and Tortoisesvn for Windows Explorer integration.

Comment: @VinShahrdar when do you see these warnings? is there an example?

Comment: @rikkigibson Yes. The line of code. Currently, I'm going though each compiler warning one by one and doing SVN Blame to see which one is more recent.

Comment: @bahrep They are simply the compiler warnings that you see if you view Windows < ErrorList < Warnings tab. Unfortunately, I don't have an available example.

Comment: Ah, so if you have a script to get a blame for each warning with the date of the revision, it should be pretty easy to parse the date out in the scripting language of your choice and sort.

Comment: @rikkigibson Good idea! Do you have a recommended scripting language to do this? I've used Perl and Powershell to solve similar problems before.

Comment: If you're good at Perl, try that. I think it's mostly a matter of personal preference. For me it would probably be Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a script that does the following:

1. run msbuild on your solution and write the outputs somewhere
2. search the output for compiler warnings, parsing out the filename and line numbers
3. run SVN blame on those filename/line number pairs and get the date for the associated revision
4. sort the warning/blame pair by date modified.